# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

First , I created 4 table : `Artist, Genre, Album , Track` . I want to travarse through xml file , then obtain necessary data and then insert into Track table. Everything works fine , until the i try to get the `id` on `Genre` table and try to assign it to `genre_id`. When I run my program it is showing that `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable .`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')


fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'



# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>



def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    print(name, artist, album, count, rating, length ,genre)

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Everything works fine until here

```
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]


    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, len, rating, count,genre_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?)''',
        ( name, album_id, length, rating, count,genre_id) )

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can't notice specific error. Maybe something to do with the data you are trying... Check for quotes and escaping of the Genre name. It might not have gone into the db during the write.

Comment: Is `
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))` supposed to be `
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))`, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the condition if 'genre is None' as indicated below.

```
if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None :
    continue
```